# Forest does not draw diagrams/lines

Tags: diagrams, nodes, forest

I have a problem with Forest in TexLive. I never experienced this problem in TexWorks which I am used to work with. As you can see in the picture, forest does not draw lines between nodes, so it does not generate any tree diagrams. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

thanks!

[image]

Comment: please show the code as a code block not an image, so we can test it

Comment: Your input looks fine to me. As you point out, the issue may come from your editor. What engine are you using? PdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX? Try to change it, for example you can write this as the first line:
`% !TEX TS-program = lualatex`

Comment: Ok, that solved it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by using the wrong compiler.